# Splitting pasted data in userform textboxes by rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

So I am trying to copy and paste data of 2 columns and 19 rows into a userform with 2 columns and 19 rows of textboxes - so the user form will match the data being pasted. I cannot figure out how to get the 2nd,3rd,4th....etc rows of data to populate in the user form.

This is the code I am using for the column split:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 Dim splittext
 splittext = Split(Me.TextBox1.Value, vbTab)
 If UBound(splittext) > LBound(splittext) Then
  Me.TextBox1.Value = splittext(LBound(splittext))
  Me.TextBox2.Value = splittext(LBound(splittext) + 1)
End If
End Sub
```

How would I make it so when I paste all the data (2 columns and 19 rows) into TextBox1 - the rest of the textboxes populate with the correct data?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Per Request: here is some sample data:

A | B

1 | 20

2 | 21

3 | 22

4 | 23

5 | 24

...down to 19 in column A and 38 in column B

Comment: Can you add sample data please. The `Split()` code you have posted won't produce a 19 x 2 array.

Comment: Ambie, I edited my post with some sample data. unfortunately because of where I work I cannot give real data or attach sheets. Thanks!